# Where do I put a loginView in a storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

Newest Xcode. Storyboards for iPhone and iPad.
Generated an application with two tab views. I see them both in the storyboard.

Now I'd like to have a situation where I want a login screen to pop up before the first tab. Is that something I do in the storyboard? or should I code this manually?

Comment: By "2 tab views" do you mean two view controllers bound to a tab each on a tab view controller? And by "before the first tab" do you mean you want to display it before the user gets the chance to select a tab? If so, you'll want to conditionally "present" this login view controller from code, but you can design it in the storyboard and reference it from the code by its identifier.

Comment: yes. that sounds right. the appearance of the login window is conditional upon lack of previous "remember me" being used and/or a rejection of the remember me credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* do it with a storyboard. One way would be to make the login view controller the initial scene in the storyboard. Another would be to arrange for the view controller from the initial scene programmatically present the login view controller before doing anything else.

Storyboards and .xib files are tools for creating whatever user interface you want, whether that's a login screen or something else. Use them if they're convenient or otherwise provide some benefit, and feel free to skip them if something else works better for you.